# OpenGL Using built-in lighting or custom one with shaders

Tags: opengl, shader, lwjgl

I just found out that OpenGL has built-in lighting which can be enabled with `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);`. Why does tutorials etc. use custom one made with shaders? There must be a reason. What does built-in lighting do worse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OpenGL has built-in lighting

No, it does not. All such things were [removed from OpenGL in 3.1 and put into the compatibility profile](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts). Which is *not* required to be supported.

> What does built-in lighting do worse?

Everything. It does everything worse.

Fixed function lighting is per-vertex, while shader-based lighting can be whatever you want: per-vertex, per-fragment, whatever. Fixed-function lighting doesn't work with deferred rendering, lighting pre-passes, or various other rendering techniques. Fixed-function lighting can't handle HDR or gamma correct illumination.

There is nothing that fixed-function lighting can do that user-defined lighting cannot. While there is a ton of stuff that user-defined lighting can do that fixed-function can't.

It is good that modern OpenGL tutorials don't teach that outdated garbage.

Comment: How about glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH). Is it good to use or should I make custom one in geometry shader?